# Trying to open and close a file inside a function

Tags: c++, function, ifstream

Having trouble getting my num_of_lines function to run. I do need to open and close the file inside the function, and will have to do the same for a couple other functions also. This is so I can get information from the begging of the file (I can't use any other functions that would allow me to do otherwise, because we have not learned them in class yet). I'm getting two errors:

```
hello.cpp:14:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'file'; did you mean
      'fill'?
    ilines.open(file);        //does file need to be a c-string
                ^~~~
                fill

hello.cpp:14:12: error: no matching member function for call to 'open'
    ilines.open(file);        //does file need to be a c-string
```

Not sure what to do, thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
#define die(errmsg) {cerr << errmsg << endl; exit(1);} 
using namespace std;

int num_of_lines(string name)
{
    int cnt3 = 0;
    string line;

    ifstream ilines;     //Do I need to check for successful opening and closing each time

    ilines.open(file);        //does file need to be a c-string

    if(ilines.is_open())
    {
        while(getline(ilines, line))cnt3++;   
    }  
    ilines.close(); 
    return(cnt3);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ 
    int num_of_lines(string name);

    string file;
    file = argv[1];

    if(argc == 1)die("usage: mywc your_file"); 

    ifstream ifs;

    ifs.open(file);

    if(ifs.is_open())
    {

        ifs.close();

        int a;

        a = num_of_lines(file);
        cout <<"Lines: " << a << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cerr <<"Could not open: " << file << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    //ifs.close();

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Your parameter is called `name`.

Comment: ...And yes, it must be a C-style string, which you can get thus: `name.c_str()`

Comment: I changed ifs.open(file) to ifs.open(name.c_str()) and I'm getting segmentation fault: 11

Comment: So simplify the code as far as you can while still reproducing the error, and see how it looks.

Comment: Isn't it a problem that you have `int num_of_lines(string name);` inside your main? Doesn't this try to declare an int initialized from a string...? Or is this a legal way to declare a function header in c++?

Comment: `file = argv[1]; if(argc == 1)die("usage: mywc your_file");` are the wrong way around: You need to check `argc` first, then access `argv[1]`.

Comment: Does this even compile for you? What do you mean `for(int i = 2; i < argv.size();) ifs.close();`? What is `size` for a `char**`? And why is the iteration `++i` missing? And what does your loop do other than try to close `ifs` many times without opening it again? Shouldn't you keep updating `name/file` in this loop? And do you give it a filename when you call it after compiling? It seems to work for me, at least it doesn't die for an empty input file...

Comment: @AndrasDeak that is a function declaration. It's legal but redundant because the function is already visible

Comment: Thanks, @MattMcNabb, it seemed weird to me anyway. I haven't yet seen any function declarations in `main`, so I wasn't sure if it was illegal or simply I've missed it up till now (especially with all the fishy stuff going on in the asker's example).

Answer (score 2):

You have couple of problems.

1. The variable `file` is not defined in `num_of_lines`. You can fix the very easily by using `file` as the argument instead of `name.

   ```
   int num_of_lines(string file)
   {
      ...
   }
   ```

   You can also use

   ```
   int num_of_lines(string const& file)
   {
      ...
   }
   ```

   to avoid making a copy of the `std::string`.
2. Assuming `file` is of type `std::string`, you may have to use `file.c_str()` in the call to open depending on the version of C++ standard your compiler supports.

   If you have a C++11 compliant compiler, you can use:

   ```
   string file;
   ifstream ilines;
   ilines.open(file);
   ```

   If you only have a C++03 compliant compiler, you'll have to use:

   ```
   string file;
   ifstream ilines;
   ilines.open(file.c_str());
   ```

Comment: there's a few other problems too